# How I can use $_FILES value without input that has `file` attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

In my case I manipulate an image using client-side javascript, because I want to scale it before uploading it:

```js
$("#base_img_to_compress").on("change", (e) => {
  resizeImage(source, 1440, 1080).then((imgData) => {
    appendToFormHiddenImageInput("base_img_data",imgData);
  });
});

$("#upload_form").on("submit",(e)=>{
    $.ajax({
      method:"POST",

      //How I can configure the postdata here ?
    })

});

function appendToFormHiddenImageInput(name, imgData) {
  const child = $("#upload_form").children("input[name=" + name + "]");
  if (child.length > 0) {
    child.remove();
  }
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "hidden";
  input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  input.setAttribute("name", name);
  input.setAttribute("value", imgData);
  $("#upload_form").append(input);
}

function resizeImage(element, width, height) {
  const element_file = element.files[0];
  return imageConversion.compressAccurately(element_file, {
    quality: 0.7,
    type: "image/png",
    width: width,
    height: height,
    size: 80
  }).then((file) => {
    return imageConversion.filetoDataURL(file);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/WangYuLue/image-conversion/build/conversion.js"></script>

<form id="upload_form">
  <button type="submit" id="savebtn">Save me</button>
</form>
<input id="base_img_to_compress" type="file" />
```

The php script that handles the upload is rather simple:

```php
$file = $_FILES['base_img_data'];

if($file['tmp_name']){
  echo "FILE UPLOADED";
  exit;
}

echo "FILE NOT UPLOADED";
```

But in order for `$_FILES` to work need the data to be uploaded as `multipart/form-data` where the `base_img_data` must be encoded as base64 string. Is there a way to do this at my javascript without using an `<input type="file" />` input element as [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) say so?

In other words the part that troubles me is this piece of javascript:

```
$("#upload_form").on("submit",(e)=>{
    $.ajax({
      method:"POST",

      //How I can configure the postdata here ?
    })

});
```

I mean, I need to populate the ajax accordingly in order to emulate a multipart form upload without using an input field that has `file` attribute. But in my case, I use hidden input fields with values encoded as base64, therefore the PHP won't recognize the incoming uploaded file using `$_FILES` magic variable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append; see the examples section for one involving files.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags - or explain how this problem is related to JS, PHP, HTML, **and** jQuery

Comment: But $.ajax is a Jquery method.

Comment: Yes, it is. But you haven't told us which part of all that code is not working as expected. If the files don't reach the PHP script as expected, that might be a JS problem. If the request is sent properly by the browser, but not handled properly by the server, that might be a PHP problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick Answer

You have to manually build your own `FormData` object. This is an approach:

```js
const formData = new FormData();

$("#upload_form :input").each((index,element)=>{
    let value = $(element).val();
    if($(element).attr('type') == "hidden"){
        formData.append($(element).attr('name'),DataURIToBlob(value),`myfile_${index}.png`);
    }
    formData.append($(element).attr('name'),value);
});


function DataURIToBlob(dataURI) {
    const splitDataURI = dataURI.split(',')
    const byteString = splitDataURI[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0 ? atob(splitDataURI[1]) : decodeURI(splitDataURI[1])
    const mimeString = splitDataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++){
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString })
}
```

Then do the ajax call like that:

```js
$.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    data: formData,
    url: "./script.php",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: ()=>{
        alert("BANZAI");
    }
})
```

In your example a complete submit method is:

```
$("#upload_form").on("submit",(e)=>{
                
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();

    $("#upload_form :input").each((index,element)=>{
        let value = $(element).val();
        
        if($(element).attr('type') == "hidden"){
            console.log(formData);
            formData.append($(element).attr('name'),DataURIToBlob(value),`myfile_${index}.png`);
        }
        formData.append($(element).attr('name'),value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        data: formData,
        url: "./script.php",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: ()=>{
            alert("BANZAI");
        }
    })
});

function DataURIToBlob(dataURI) {
    const splitDataURI = dataURI.split(',')
    const byteString = splitDataURI[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0 ? atob(splitDataURI[1]) : decodeURI(splitDataURI[1])
    const mimeString = splitDataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++){
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString })
}
```

Please notice that upon ajax alongside with `data` option I use these options as well:

```
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
```

If they are not set to false then the upload won't happen.

## What if I also have/populate hidden input fields that do not contain file data?

Upon placing input differentiate it using a data attribute, for example, `data-file` once you dynamically add it. In your example an approach should be to replace the following function:

```
function appendToFormHiddenImageInput(name, imgData) {
  const child = $("#upload_form").children("input[name=" + name + "]");
  if (child.length > 0) {
    child.remove();
  }
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "hidden";
  input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  input.setAttribute("name", name);
  input.setAttribute("value", imgData);
  input.setAttribute("data-file",true); // <<< This appends the distingushing indicator
  $("#upload_form").append(input);
}
```

The use the following submit method:

```
$("#upload_form").on("submit",(e)=>{
                
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();

    $("#upload_form :input").each((index,element)=>{
        let value = $(element).val();
        
        if($(element).attr('type') == "hidden" && $(element).data('file') === true ){
            console.log(formData);
            formData.append($(element).attr('name'),DataURIToBlob(value),`myfile_${index}.png`);
        }
        formData.append($(element).attr('name'),value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        data: formData,
        url: "./script.php",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: ()=>{
            alert("BANZAI");
        }
    })
});

function DataURIToBlob(dataURI) {
    const splitDataURI = dataURI.split(',')
    const byteString = splitDataURI[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0 ? atob(splitDataURI[1]) : decodeURI(splitDataURI[1])
    const mimeString = splitDataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++){
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString })
}
```

Pay attention to the line:

```
if($(element).attr('type') == "hidden" && $(element).data('file') === true )
```

I also check if the field is an input file or not.

Also pay attention to:

```
input.setAttribute("data-file",true);
```

---

## Why does it work?

It works because using form-data you make a POST encoded as `multipart/form-data`. $_FILES is a parsed value from a body that seems to be a file. In our case we re-constructed the form as multipart one at line:

```
formData.append($(element).attr('name'),DataURIToBlob(value),`myfile_${index}.png`);
```

At function `appendToFormHiddenImageInput`

## Miscellanous

In my case I set a name with fixed file extension, if you want to manage it manually use the blob [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/type). I could do it like this:

```
const name = `myfile_${index}`
value = DataURIToBlob(value);

let suffix = 'png'

swich(value.type)
{
  // handle suffix here
}
name = `${name}.${suffix}`

formData.append($(element).attr('name'),value,name);
```

Replacing the:

```
   formData.append($(element).attr('name'),DataURIToBlob(value),`myfile_${index}.png`);
```

Also, I made sure, that on the php side I had the appropriate value on `upload_max_filesize` setting it `php.ini`.